# How to get not find multiple values in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

If I search entities by array in doctrine like:

```
$names = ['Jim', 'Anne', 'Kara'];
$em->findByName($names);
```

How can I know then, which names could not be found? Of course, I can loop the returned array and check for each name again. But maybe there is a doctrine method that returns not found names?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't achieve it using [EntityRepository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) apis, so I would use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) together, for a single line solution, as follow:

```
$names = ['Jim', 'Anne', 'Kara'];
$res = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->findByName($names);
$notFound = array_diff($names, array_map(function($obj){ return $obj->getName(); }, $res));
```

Consider that `array_diff` use `===` operator to compare values, so names must be exactly equal to be duplicates. If you don't want to take care about lower/upper cases, then convert all with `strtolower`.

```
$notFound = array_diff(array_map('strtolower', $names), array_map(function($obj){ return strtolower($obj->getName()); }, $res));
```

Of course I assumed that you have declared `name` getter in your entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EntityRepository` with `Criteria`;

Assuming you are looking for entity `User` with field `name` and you want to find all `Users` whose name is not in array `$names` code could look like this

```
$names = ['Jim', 'Anne', 'Kara'];
$repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
$users = $repository->matching(new Criteria(Criteria::expr()->notIn("name", $names)));
```